# How can I get the information of the newest version of unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to create a script that looks up the newest version of unity, but have been failing for a while now.
Is there some kind of API or something else that could give me the newest version and the release date of unity?

I've been trying to get the information from https://unity3d.com/de/get-unity/update with a c# script by just searching in the HTML but I think this will cause problems in the future.

Comment: which information exactly do you mean? If there is a new version available?

Comment: @derHugo I only need the release Date and the Version.

Comment: I don't think there is any API. Getting it by HTML seems to be the only option currently though ofcourse agree .. this mgiht get messy .. espeiclly since the according `<div>` don't even have a proper id so it will get hard to parse for the correct texts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also see a list of released versions here:
http://symbolserver.unity3d.com/000Admin/history.txt

Editor script to check and download updates:
https://github.com/UnityCommunity/UnityLibrary/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/Editor/HelpLastRelease.cs

Answer (score 0):

I quickly tried to do some tests with the 'check for updates' feature of Unity3D editor.

I have found that you can know the last version available in that way:

> GET
>   https://updatecheck.unity3d.com/cgi-bin/updatecheck.cgi

**Params:**

> - version: my Unity3D editor send '0'
> - versionString: my Unity3D editor send 2018.3.7f1 (9e14d22a41bb) [string format url encoded]

**Headers:**

> X-UNITY-FLAGS: 40xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx28
>     X-UNITY-CHECK: 1
>     X-UNITY-AUTH: db4fc87f2e73bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx8a2b
>     X-UNITY-HASH: 1d0a9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2aa
>     X-UNITY-USER-ID: 2xxxxx0

**Full request URL (Example):**

```
https://updatecheck.unity3d.com/cgi-bin/updatecheck.cgi?version=0&versionString=2018.3.7f1%20%289e14d22a41bb%29
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "latestversionstring":"2019.2.0f1 (20c1667945cf)",
    "latestversion":99999,
    "latestversionmessage":"A new version of Unity is available. Please update to the latest released version at your convenience. Release notes available on the download site. Click the \"Download Installer\" button.",
    "updateurl":"http://unity3d.com/update/",
    "updateinterval":3600
}
```

As you can see, the response is a Json response with the last version available and other info used by Unity editor (Unfortunately, the release date of the last version is not present).

Another problem is that we don't know if '*Unity Header parameters*' (X-UNITY-*) is based on current user session (maybe those params expire after 'x' time?)

> Warn: I have obfuscated headers values because those params are based on my user session.

---

**How did I find header parameters?**

- Download fiddler (Web Debugger) to sniff HTTP/HTTPS requests.
- Open Unity3D and open Fiddler
- Inside Unity3D click on *Help -> Check for Updates*
- Inside Fiddler you can see the request appear

[image: fiddler request]

- Click that request.

[image: fiddler request details]

> TIP: you must install root cert to see https request, google for more infos

You could try to do further tests to see if the parameters change, and maybe if this request accepts additional parameters to get more information in the response.

Unfortunately this is the only idea that came to my mind to take the latest version of Unity available.